# Google Drive API How can I find the path of a file?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to find the path of a file when fetching a file list with the Google Drive API.

Right now, I'm able to fetch file properties (currently only fetching checksum, id, name, and mimeType):

```
results = globalShares.service.files().list(pageSize=1000,corpora='user',fields='nextPageToken, files(md5Checksum, id, name, mimeType)').execute()
items = results.get('files',[])
nextPageToken = results.get('nextPageToken',False)
for file in items:
    print("===========================================================")
    pp.pprint(file)
print(str(len(items)))
print(nextPageToken)
```

[List documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#parameters) (parameters fed to the list() method)

[Files documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) (properties returned with each file)

Comment: Can I ask you about `the path of a file' you want? Do you want to retrieve the parent folder ID?

Comment: Yes, that's helpful though wouldn't it only return the ID of only the immediate directory above it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. When `parents` is added to `fields`, the parent folder ID of the file is returned. In your situation, you want to retrieve the folder tree of the file. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct, I want the tree.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Try to stop thinking in terms of file paths. Google Drive is a flat filesystem, where "parent" is simply an attribute, a bit like a tag. A file can have many parents, and so could be on many paths.

Comment: @pinoyyid Thank you for your comment. Yes. I know it. From OP's situation which want to retrieve "the file path", I thought that the file has only one parent. So at first, I confirmed about it and I proposed a simple script. But from your comment, I thought that my proposal is not suitable for the file system of Google Drive. So I would like to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I thought that I have to study more and more.

Comment: @www139 From pinoyyid's comment, I thought that my proposal was not suitable for your question. So I deleted my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike please undelete your answer. It is a good answer and will help the OP very much. I suggest you should edit the answer slightly to explain that `parent[0]` is valid only of there is a single parent. The OP can extend your script to iterate parents if he has multiple paths.

Comment: @pinoyyid Thank you for replying. I could understand about your replying. So I undeleted my answer by including "Note" section. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @www139 I updated my answer by including "Note" section. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks great. I'll play around with it tonight/tomorrow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- You want to retrieve a folder tree from a file in own Google Drive.

  - You want to retrieve the file path. So in your case, it retrieves a parent folder above each file and folder.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.
- You have already been able to get the file metadata using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Unfortunately, in the current stage, the folder tree of the file cannot directly be retrieved by the Google API. So it is required to prepare a script for achieving it. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

This sample script retrieves the folder tree of the file. When you use this script, please set the file ID.

```
fileId = '###'  # Please set the file ID here.

tree = []  # Result
file = globalShares.service.files().get(fileId=fileId, fields='id, name, parents').execute()
parent = file.get('parents')
if parent:
    while True:
        folder = service.files().get(
            fileId=parent[0], fields='id, name, parents').execute()
        parent = folder.get('parents')
        if parent is None:
            break
        tree.append({'id': parent[0], 'name': folder.get('name')})

print(tree)
```

#### Result:

In the case that the file has the three-layer structure, when you run the script, the following object is returned.

```
[
  {
    "id": "folderId3",
    "name": "folderName3"
  },
  {
    "id": "folderId2",
    "name": "folderName2"
  },
  {
    "id": "folderId1",
    "name": "My Drive"  # This is the root folder.
  }
]
```

- The 1st element is the bottom layer.

#### Note:

- In this script, from OP's situation which want to retrieve "the file path", it supposes that each file has only one parent. At the file system of Google Drive, each file can have multiple parents. If in your situation, there are several files which have the multiple parents, this script returns the 1st element of the array of `parents`. Please be careful this. This is also mentioned by [pinoyyid's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618533/google-drive-api-how-can-i-find-the-path-of-a-file?noredirect=1#comment101704368_57618533).

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [getfilelistpy](https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy)

  - As another sample, there is a library for retrieving the folder tree from the Google Drive.

Comment: the script hardcodes `parent[0]` but there could be multiple parents.

Comment: @pinoyyid Thank you for your comment. Yes. I know it. From OP's situation which want to retrieve "the file path", I thought that the file has only one parent. So at first, I confirmed about it and I proposed a simple script. But from your comment, I thought that my proposal is not suitable for the file system of Google Drive. So I would like to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I thought that I have to study more and more.

Comment: In v3 API, since Sept 2020, Google now has a single parent model.  So, @Tanaike, you were just ahead of the curve ;-)   
See [api/v3/ref-single-parent](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-single-parent)