# How to get directory path in Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Currently, I am able to retrieve the Folders/Directory that owned by me and its returning a list of result as expected.

Here is the code snippet,

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    queries = [
        "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
        "'my_email@gmail.com' in owners"

    ]
    drive_str_query = queries[0] if len(queries) == 1 else " and ".join(queries)
    results = service.files().list(q=drive_str_query,
                                   pageSize=1000,
                                   spaces='drive',
                                   fields="nextPageToken, files(*)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This snippet returns data with sufficient fields [as mentioned in here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations), But, it doesn't include a ***relative/absolute path to the Folder/Directory***

Is there any way to findout the path to the directory/folder?

Comment: AFAIK google drive doesn't even *have* a concept of file paths. I'm pretty sure it allows files to exist in multiple folders at once.

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57618533

Comment: Just as a curiosity to what Aran-Fey said, if you select a file on Google Drive and press Shift+Z you can add it to a folder without moving it. Any file/folder can be inside any number of folders. The web interface just shows the shortest path to your root folder

Comment: These are new pieces of information to my knowledge. Anyway thanks, guys :)