# how to get folder parent path using google drive API without using recursion?

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I am trying to get path from selected folder up to root(My Drive) using parent id.

nested folder :

```
My Drive ___ Folder1 __ Foder1.1 ____ Folder1.1.1  ____ Folder1.1.1.1(selected folder)
        |           |            \___ Folder1.1.2  \___ Folder1.1.1.2
        |           |__ Folder1.2
        |___ Folder2
```

Drive API :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
```

For now, I'm using recursion to get the path, but this takes quite a while.

my code:

```
public function getParentFolder($parentId)
{
    $result = [];

    /** options */
    $optParams = [
        'fields' => 'id, name, parents'
    ];

    /** GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId */
    $response = $this->getFileService($parentId, $optParams);

    if ($response->getParents() != "" && in_array($response->getName(), ['My Drive']) === false) {
        
        /** get parent data */
        $newParent = $response->getParents();

        /** get data */
        $result[] = [
            'id' => $response->getId(),
            'name' => $response->getName(),
        ];

        /** call function again */
        $newResult = $this->getParentFolder($newParent[0]);

        /** merge data */
        $result = array_merge($result, $newResult);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

result :

```
[
  {
    "id": "Folder1.1.1 Id",
    "name": "Folder1.1.1"
  },
  {
    "id": "Folder1.1 Id",
    "name": "Folder1.1"
  },
  {
    "id": "Folder1 Id",
    "name": "Folder1"
  },
  {
    "id": "My Drive Id",
    "name": "My Drive"  # This is the root folder.
  }
]
```

is it possible to get the folder path without recursion?

Comment: I'm not familar with Google's drive, but I can see that `$response->getParents()` can return multiple parents, whereas you always only use the first? Might the other parents be in that array, and the one you're looking for simply be the last? So: `$lastParent = array_pop($newParent);`? I don't know. Or perhaps you simply need all those parents in the array?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware from drive doc, it says folder has only 1 parent now. [parent doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-single-parent)

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So, the multiple parents you seek are not presented in that array.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I am trying to get list parent path (until root path) from selected folder using parent id.`, I cannot understand your expected values. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected goal?

Comment: @Tanaike i want to get folder name and id. For example tree: `Folder1->Folder1.1->Foder1.1.1 -> Folder1.1.1.1(selected folder)`. i want get list name and id from (folder1, folder1.1, folder1.1.1);

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected values. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: It might have been answered by @tanaike at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618533/google-drive-api-how-can-i-find-the-path-of-a-file